# Initializing values to constructor using main method

Tags: java

How to initialize the values in constructor that the values cannot be passed by object and that we could pass them from main method?

```
  class ex
    {
        int a,b;
        ex()
        {
            this.a=b;  
        }

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            //here we pass the values to that consructor ex
            ex obj=new ex();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem and is this really JavaEE ?

Comment: please elaborate on what the actual problem is

Answer (score 3):

make an overloaded constructor which accepts two arguments.

```
public ex(int a, int b) {
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
}

public static void main(String...args){
 ex obj = new ex(1,2)
}
```

> values canntot be passed by object we should pass from main method

If i understand correctly, you want to pass arguments from the main method and nitialize them in your constructor, the only was to do is by passing them to the constuctor while object creation

Answer (score 0):

You can call setter method from constructor if don't want to display initialization values while declaring new object.

Please see code below for reference :

```
class Testcl {
```

int a,b;

Testcl(){
    setValues(1,2);
}

private void setValues(int a, int b){
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b; 
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    Testcl test = new Testcl();
    System.out.println("a : " + test.a + " b : " + test.b);
}}

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to say is that this does actually "work" ... in the sense that it compiles and executes without any errors.

```
    int a,b;  // default initialized to 'zero'

    ex() {
        this.a=b;  // assigns 'zsro' to a.
    }
```

But of course, it doesn't achieve anything ... because `a` is *already* `zero` at that point.

Now the `main` method could assign something to the `a` and/or `b` fields *after* the constructor returns.  But there is no way (in pure Java<sup>1</sup>) to get some non-zero value into `b` *before* the constructor is called ... if that is what you are asking.

The practical solution is to just to add `a` and `b` arguments to the constructor.

---

<sup>1 - a non-pure Java solution might be to "monkey around" with the bytecodes of the constructor so that it does what you "need" to do.  But that's pretty horrible, and horrible solutions have a tendency of coming back to bite you.</sup>

Comment: As `int`s, `a` and `b` would be initialized to zero, not null.